# line terminator instead of blank space pandas read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set that has a line terminator  in my time field like below:

**Text file:**

```
num1  Name    Num   dan    pan   fran    time
----  ------  ----  ----   ----  -----   ----------------------------
52345 john    12    True   True  False   <LF>
43214 Matt    56    False  False True    2008-12-12 01:01:47 UTC+0000<LF>
12345 Adam    13    True   True  False   <LF>
54321 Sam     23    False  True  True    <LF>
```

**Current Code:**

I am currently attempting to read it into a `pandas.DataFrame` like below:

```
pd.read_csv(file.txt, delim_white_space=True, skiprows=range(1,2)).fillna("NONE)
```

**Current Result:**

I am getting an output that has my data shifted because I am not able to recognize the blank value in my time field like below:

```
    num1  Name    Num   dan    pan   fran    time
    52345 john    12    True   True  False   <LF>
43214 Matt    56    False  False True    2008-12-12 01:01:47 UTC+0000
    12345 Adam    13    True   True  False   <LF>
    54321 Sam     23    False  True  True    <LF>
```

**Question:**

How can I either pre-parse my data to make the time field contain blank space or "NONE" and then read into pandas appropriately or have pandas recognize there is a missing value?

**Expected output:**

```
num1  Name    Num   dan    pan   fran    time
52345 john    12    True   True  False   NONE
43214 Matt    56    False  False True    2008-12-12 01:01:47 UTC+0000
12345 Adam    13    True   True  False   NONE
54321 Sam     23    False  True  True    NONE
```

Comment: Is your input data stored in a text file? Do you have access to tools like `sed`? `sed -i.bck 's/<LF>/NONE/g' datafile.txt` may very well do what you want.

Comment: it is in a txt file, unfortunately i am stuck in windows / python for processing.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see your problem. Though, how is Pandas able to to parse the date field correctly? I assume then, that those `<LF>`s are symbolic, rather than literal text.

Comment: correct, pandas is reading it with the "\t" as a delimiter, it just doesnt recognize the fact that there is no value for the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [`pandas.read_fwf`:](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html)

**Code:**

```
df = pd.read_fwf('file1', skiprows=range(1, 2)).fillna("NONE")
```

**Results:**

```
    num1  Name  Num    dan    pan   fran                          time
0  52345  john   12   True   True  False                          NONE
1  43214  Matt   56  False  False   True  2008-12-12 01:01:47 UTC+0000
2  12345  Adam   13   True   True  False                          NONE
3  54321   Sam   23  False   True   True                          NONE
```

Comment: This worked, will add a check in  a minute. Thank you.